# How can I initialise a pointer member to point at its encapsulating instance?

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, this, forward-declaration

Suppose I had the following:

```
class A; // forward declaration

class A {
public:
    A(A* parent) : parent(parent) {}
    A* parent;
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() : A(this) {}
    void foo() {}
};
```

When instantiating two separate instances of class `B`, the `parent` pointers are the same in each of the instances. Any idea why?

EDIT: I believe the above now more closely models what I have in my code.

Comment: `this` should work just fine. Can you post the actual error message?

Comment: The value of `this` (the address of the object) is perfectly fine to use at that point, whether the object's contents are initialized or not.

Comment: There's no error message per se, it's just that two separate instances of the class are pointing to the same memory location.

Comment: You need a copy constructor. Two objects pointing two the same is a symptom of missing copy ctor.

Comment: Could it be something to do with the fact that in my actual code the class equivalent to `A` is pure virtual?

Comment: I am not sure. Maybe you should post some more code of the problem and someone can figure it out.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `it doesn't work`? What is the exact error message you get? Is it a compile-time error or a runtime one?

Comment: I'm wondering what's the point of making an object store a pointer to itself.  To get to the `parent` member, you need to have a pointer or reference to the object already, so the `parent` pointer doesn't tell you anything you don't already know.

Comment: @Wyzard: Agree if it never changes to something else, but this could just be initialization?

Comment: @Wyzard It's just an initial value, `parent` will be set to other instances of `A` later on.

Comment: If an instance is copied, should the copy's `parent` be initialized to point to itself, or should it point to the original instance that the new one was copied from?

Comment: @Wyzard I'd have it point to itself.

Comment: Just as a note: If your class is more complex than you show here it could be unsafe to use the this pointer in the initialiser list.

Comment: @user2672165 My equivalent of class `A` really is that minimal. My class `B` equivalent is merely a few variables with accessors and a single non-modifying method, nothing more. But I'll bear that in mind, thanks.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your problem, using your updated code with `A` and `B`.  I add a `main()` method that has two variables `B first;` and `B second;`, and each one's `parent` points to itself as it should.

Comment: for those suggesting he needs a copy constructor, that would depend on how "instantiating two separate instances of class B" is being done.  Is the OP copying ala B1 = B2?  If so, I would agree but if doing B1 = new B() and B2 = new B(), then something else, not shown in the post, is causing the behavior described...

Comment: @Eric Having trawled through the places of instantiation there indeed a B1 = B2 style line buried in there to blame. With the proper copy constructor/assignment functions the problem has now been solved. Apologies for its omission!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a copy constructor.  Your default constructor isn't invoked when an instance is copied, and the compiler-generated copy constructor will copy the `parent` pointer from the original instance.

```
A(A const &other) : parent(this) {}
```

You may want to write a copy-assignment operator too, to preserve the `parent` pointer when one instance is assigned to another.

Also, think about what should happen when copying or assigning from an instance whose `parent` has been changed from its default.  In that case, should the copy/assignee get the same parent as the original?  If so, your copy constructor and assignment operator will have to check whether `parent == this` and behave differently depending on the result.  It may be simpler to just use `nullptr` as the default value — either way you need special-case handling for instances without parents, but a null pointer at least makes it *obvious* that no "real" parent has been assigned yet.

Comment: Just to avoid compiler messages I would omit 'other'.

Comment: Would I need a copy constructor for both `A` and `B`? Or just `A`?

Comment: Perhaps you are right about the `nullptr` idea, I was merely following the conventions of [Disjoint Set data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) which propose that roots of trees point at themselves, but I don't see that being much different to the roots being null anyhow.

Comment: Or maybe you should just make these classes non-copyable and non-assignable.  If a copy of a tree node should have the same parent as the original, that parent should be made aware of its new child, which may incur significant processing (e.g. to rebalance the tree), and may not even be supported (e.g. a binary tree node that has two children already).  On the other hand, if a copy of a tree node is a new root with no parent, then it's not really a copy at all, and should've been created with some other constructor.

Comment: I agree, I do think these should probably be made non-copyable and non-assignable. I will look up best practices on doing so now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a semicolon after the class definition. It's missing in the example you provided. Compilers sometimes give cryptic error messages for this.

Comment: No that's not it, the code example above is a simplified version that I typed out by hand quickly - the lack of the trailing `;` was a mistake on my part but isn't the source of my problem.